# Testing Visual Studio 2008 Package

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, vspackage

I'm developing a Visual Studio Integration Package.  When I try to run the Unit Tests that are included in the unit test project that is included in the template I get the following failure on the first test:

> The test adapter 'VsIdeHostAdapter'
>   threw an exception while running test
>   'MenuItemCallback'. Call was rejected
>   by callee. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))

It's intermittent- a new instance of Visual Studio always spins up, then sometimes it works but usually fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known issue- the built-in tests have some problems.